# Perfmon metrics in Jmeter doesn't show up in ROWS tab. Metrics are already defined

Tags: jmeter, perfmon

I have defined almost 10 metrics in perfmon in jmeter. But when i execute the load testing, I see that only 2 of the metrics I can select in the ROWS tab of perfmon, where you can Check or Uncheck the metric to be graphed.

Can someone explain what is the issue and its solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there should be 2 things to check if you are not receiving Metrics during the load test.

1. Check if the login which you used to execute the 'serverAgent' has the permission to execute the commands / operations you set in the metrics (e.g. some ops can only be executed via root or some other special login). If its the case, terminate serverAgent and execute it from the login with permission to do so. Metrics will start appearing.
2. If Metrics still dont appear, then login and execute the command you set in Metrics. If there is no display , then it means there is no output for perfmon to collect so it is not showing anything.